# Reinterpreting std::string to unsigned int array

Tags: c++

I want to achieve something like that in C (ARM platform):

```
char a[] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44};
uint32_t *aUint = (uint32_t *)a;
```

Then I can use:

```
printf("%X", aUint[1]);
```

and the result will be:

```
0x11223344
```

Now I would like to do the same in C++, but when I try to do something like this (assuming string length % 4 == 0):

```
std::string str("some human readable    ");
uint32_t *dataByWord = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(&str);
```

I get output:

```
error: cast from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*’ to ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

Is there a way to reinterpret input string to avoid any loops or copying?

Comment: Don't cast, *convert* (e.g. by bit shifting). Otherwise you're heading straight to UB land ...

Comment: That's not valid C code either. You can't reinterpret it neither in C nor C++ because numbers have to be aligned some way, and the char array doesn't guarantee it. You are just lucky that x86 accepts it.

Comment: What's `data` in your example?

Comment: Does C++ have relaxed rules on strict aliasing?  Given `char a[] = {...};`, `uint32_t *aUint = (uint32_t *)a;` violates strict aliasing in C, and in my experience can result in `SIGBUS` on certain architectures even in C++.

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, this is plain UB. You can only `reinterpret_cast` this way to a `char` or `unsigned char` pointer.

Comment: I assumed ARM32 architecture this is why (I think) `uint32_t *aUint = (uint32_t *)a;` works I think. Yeah, I see now, that its bad idea.

Comment: maybe you're missing a '*' in your reinterpret_cast (should be <uint32_t*> and not <uint32_t>).

Comment: @EricNicolas That's not the only thing missing. That will fix the compiler error, but it will reinterpret the `std::string` object itself, not the string data it contains.

Answer (score -1):

The solution:

```
uint32_t *dataByWord = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(str.c_str());
```